# motherboard issue with installing 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, asus

I built myself a gaming desktop and I tried installing 12.04 on a new EUFI motherboard but, it missed the OS. I tried installing 13.04 and it worked perfectly. Is there a way to install 12.04 also on my hard as second partition. 12.04 was really what I wanted to install as my main OS.

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the latest version **12.04.2** 64bit? This should not give you any issues with uefi. I know because I use it.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it last week and it was 12.04.2.

Comment: After reinstalling a few times, I finally got it working now. Now, all I see is during the booting process I see the purple screen is similar to what you see in virtualbox with ''Ubuntu 12.04'' instead of the Ubuntu default logo.